# How to count and illustrate agents based on specific parmeter values in bar charts?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

My source is generating an agent called `Sitz` with several parameters which get their value out of a database. One of the parameters is `product_type`.

Now I would like to count and illustrate the number of `Sitz` for each `product_type` in bar chart.
I am thinking of a bar chart which shows 2 bars, one with **Sitz product_type = A400S** and one with **Sitz product_type = A660**.

My idea is to write something like `sink.count(agent.product_type = "A400S")` as value in the bar charts data section, but this is not the right way. What would be the right code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of ways, here is one:

First, create a variable `countA440S`. Then, in the sink, write

```
if (agent.product_type.equals("A400S")) {
    countA440S++;
}
```

In your bar chart, link it to the variable as below:
[image]

PS: Best always check the example models first, many show how to apply these basic techniques